# Why would somebody want to turn off v-sync?

Tags: vsync

From [this recent article about technical limitations of UWP](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/03/tim-sweeney-to-microsoft-universal-windows-platform-can-should-must-and-will-die/), I've found inability to turn off v-sync listed as a negative point.

I understand lowering graphics settings like texture quality, various effects and changing resolution, which very noticeably [affect framerate and resource consumption](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117481/is-there-a-reason-to-add-options-to-not-use-advanced-game-technologies-in-a-game), but vertical synchronization doesn't seem to do any harm.

From what I know, it only removes image tearing, and as a side-effect may result in displayed framerate change from 60 to 59 (or `max_fps-1`) in some games due to faulty framerate counting algorithm, which some users may see as *literally unplayable*. From my experience, in game streams with low framerate, disabled v-sync shows as a lot of tearing frames and disgruntled viewers.

Are there any advantages to disabling v-sync? Does it cost anything performance-wise to worry about?

Comment: guys I SPECIFICALLY asked about v-sync, and not other features, and I even linked that "dupe" in my question to show that it's not the same question, please reopen

Comment: not once the word "sync" appears on the "dupe" post

Comment: Sometimes people don't have good computers to even achieve a constant 60fps, and (poorly implemented) vsync would force them down to 30 fps when they may want to render as many as possible.